# IndexError: index out of range

Tags: python

I have a loop that runs 16 times because there's 16 lines in the file it reads from, I'm using a loop to, among other things, read the first two characters of the time stamp. But I can't figure out how to keep the n variable from reaching 17. I've tried to use while conditions to limit n to 16 but to no avail. Here is my entire function, I'm trying to animate the path of hurricane Irene as detailed at http://calicoproject.org/Calico_Python_GIS:

```
def drawIrene(win):
line = Line()
n = 0
for (x,y) in dots:
    time_stamp[n] = time_stamp[n][:2]
    time_stamp[n+1] = time_stamp[n+1][:2]
    time1 = abs(int(time_stamp[n]) - 12)
    time2 = abs(int(time_stamp[n+1]) - 12)
    wait_time = abs(int(time1) - int(time2))
    x, y = ll2xy(x, y)
    c = Circle(Point(x, y), int(eye_size[n]))
    line.append(Point(x,y))
    c.fill = Color(255, 255, 0, 62)
    c.draw(win)
    t = Polygon((x, y), (x+10, y+5), (x+int(movement_speed[n]), y-int(movement_speed[n])/2))
    t.fill = Color("orange")
    t.draw(win)
    print(time1)
    print(time2)
    print()
    #print (wait_time)
    wait(wait_time)
    if n < len(dots):
        n += 1
    else:
        break
line.draw(win)
line.border = 2
```

Comment: You need to provide significantly more code context here.

Comment: Given as little context as you have, I think your problem is with the `n+1` index. So looping over 15 times instead of 16 should solve your issues

Comment: Two options:
len(dots) - 1 

or

n = 1

Comment: len(dots) - 1 worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're looping over two sequences of the same length, `dots` and `time_stamp`.  However, you're looking ahead in the `time_stamp` sequence, accessing both the current item and the next item in order to calculate the `wait_time` value. This is causing your `IndexError` on the last pass through the loop, since an `n+1` index points off the end of the list.

There are a few different ways to fix this. You could to modify your data structures so that either `dots` has one fewer element, or so that `time_stamp` has one more. Or you could simply loop one fewer time, as suggested in the comments.

But I think the best solution will be to change the logic in your loop to calculate `wait_time` differently on either the first or last cycle. For instance, you might choose to have no delay on the last cycle.

Here's some code that does just that. It special cases the last pass through, where `n` is equal to `len(time_stamp)-1`, and simply sets `wait_time` to zero in that case. Note that I'm generating `n` from the built-in `enumerate` function in the `for` loop, so it doesn't need to be initialized to zero or updated manually:

```
for n, (x, y) in enumerate(dots):
    if n < len(time_stamp)-1:
        time_stamp[n] = time_stamp[n][:2]
        time_stamp[n+1] = time_stamp[n+1][:2]
        time1 = abs(int(time_stamp[n]) - 12)
        time2 = abs(int(time_stamp[n+1]) - 12)
        wait_time = abs(int(time1) - int(time2))
    else: # special case n >= len(time_stamp)-1, which should be the last pass
        wait_time = 0
    x, y = ll2xy(x, y)
    c = Circle(Point(x, y), int(eye_size[n]))
    line.append(Point(x,y))
    c.fill = Color(255, 255, 0, 62)
    c.draw(win)
    t = Polygon((x, y), (x+10, y+5),
                (x+int(movement_speed[n]), y-int(movement_speed[n])/2))
    t.fill = Color("orange")
    t.draw(win)
    wait(wait_time)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this solution allows me to iterate through all the points on the map while still calculating my time adjustments. Much appreciated.